# onTouchEvent() и performClick() не работают так, как нужно (AndroidStudio)

Tags: android

До этого тестил приложение на другом телефоне и при нажатии на экран, метод `onTouchEvent()` работал так, как нужно, а именно: на экране был круг, и этот круг перемещался в точку касания с экраном, а при перемещении пальца круг двигался к нему.

Спустя пол года начал тестить на другом телефоне, и теперь круг не движется к точке касания с экраном, а движется только тогда, когда постоянно точку касания менять, т.е. двигать пальцем по экрану.

Метод `onTouchEvent()` был подсвечен желтым и было сказано, что нужно реализовать метод `performClick()`, я так понял, что он и отвечает за то, чтобы одно касание по экрану метод принимал как постоянное. Ну, я его реализовал, добавил в метод `onTouchEvent()`, добавил ещё `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` помимо `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`, хотя раньше и с одним `ACTION_MOVE` работало. Но в итоге все равно, круг смещается к координатам касания с экраном только в том случае, если один раз его коснуться (круг на мгновение сместится к точке касания) или если все время двигать пальцем по экрану.

Вот код с методами (пишу в **Android Studio**):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Game game = new Game();
    if (!game.PAUSE) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            gameManager.onTouchEvent((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            invalidate();
            performClick();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean performClick() {
    super.performClick();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации, метод `performClick()`:

> Added in API level 1
>
> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

Это значит, что при вызове этого метода, вызывается обработчик нажатия (если вы его определяли) и все остальное (как будто юзер сам нажал на кнопку).

Как я понял из вашего описания, у вас довольно тривиальная проблема — пока вы держите палец на экране, происходит его обновление (перемещение шариков и т.д.), как отпускаете — перестаёт.

Всё логично, т.к. за обновление отвечает метод `invalidate()`, который вы вызываете в переопределенном методе `onTouchEvent`. Который, в свою очередь, вызывается при вашем нажатии.

Отсюда следует, что только при нажатии на экран, он будет обновляться и ваш шарик будет двигаться.

Так что заголовок у вашего вопроса неправильный — методы работают так, как надо, только не так, как вы думали.

Вам нужно подумать, как эту логику изменить, чтобы обновление происходило не только во время касания.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, попробую что-нибудь придумать.

Да, нужно было заголовок сделать "...не работают так, как нужно МНЕ" :)

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров если ответ вас удовлетворяет, примите его как верный — для этого есть галочка чуть левее самого ответа.